When including a file in Python with an imported eel module, an error occurs
enter image description here
I am writing an application in python from an Html and Css framework.
I'm writing an application in Python with a base of Html and Css. when I run the python file, I get an error even though all the plugins are installed and everything is in the right place.
I tried reloading the libraries and reinstalling Python. since I'm not very experienced in this. Please help.
